# Tests for Linear Congruential Generator in Python

Tags: python, random, lcg

What tests should be performed for this LCG in python?

Everything that comes to my mind is: Diehard, chi-square, kol-smirnov and that's obviously enough for my purposes (its a homework) but I have read some articles and documentation about these tests to better understand them, but it is still quite abstract for me to write this in the form of a Python code

```
import numpy as np

class LCG(object):

    UZERO: np.uint32 = np.uint32(0)
    UONE : np.uint32 = np.uint32(1)

    def __init__(self, seed: np.uint32, a: np.uint32, c: np.uint32) -> None:
        self._seed: np.uint32 = np.uint32(seed)
        self._a   : np.uint32 = np.uint32(a)
        self._c   : np.uint32 = np.uint32(c)

    def next(self) -> np.uint32:
        self._seed = self._a * self._seed + self._c
        return self._seed

    def seed(self) -> np.uint32:
        return self._seed

    def set_seed(self, seed: np.uint32) -> np.uint32:
        self._seed = seed

    def skip(self, ns: np.int32) -> None:
        """
        Signed argument - skip forward as well as backward

        The algorithm here to determine the parameters used to skip ahead is
        described in the paper F. Brown, "Random Number Generation with Arbitrary Stride,"
        Trans. Am. Nucl. Soc. (Nov. 1994). This algorithm is able to skip ahead in
        O(log2(N)) operations instead of O(N). It computes parameters
        A and C which can then be used to find x_N = A*x_0 + C mod 2^M.
        """

        nskip: np.uint32 = np.uint32(ns)

        a: np.uint32 = self._a
        c: np.uint32 = self._c

        a_next: np.uint32 = LCG.UONE
        c_next: np.uint32 = LCG.UZERO

        while nskip > LCG.UZERO:
            if (nskip & LCG.UONE) != LCG.UZERO:
                a_next = a_next * a
                c_next = c_next * a + c

            c = (a + LCG.UONE) * c
            a = a * a

            nskip = nskip >> LCG.UONE

        self._seed = a_next * self._seed + c_next

#%%
np.seterr(over='ignore')

a = np.uint32(1664525)
c = np.uint32(1013904223)
seed = np.uint32(1)

rng = LCG(seed, a, c)

print(rng.next())
print(rng.next())
print(rng.next())

rng.skip(-3) # back by 3
print(rng.next())
print(rng.next())
print(rng.next())

rng.skip(-3) # back by 3
rng.skip(2) # forward by 2
print(rng.next())

#%% 10k
#np.seterr(over='ignore')

#a = np.uint32(1664525)
#c = np.uint32(1013904223)
#seed = np.uint32(1)

#rng = LCG(seed, a, c)
#q = [rng.next() for _ in range(0, 10000)]
#print(q)
```

Comment: https://csrc.nist.gov/Projects/Random-Bit-Generation/Documentation-and-Software/Guide-to-the-Statistical-Tests

Comment: Thanks.  
I know that there are no "standard" tests for rng but what "minimum" set should I choose?

Comment: I would say that the ones on the NIST list are a good minimum, although by no means a guarantee for RNG.

Comment: Is there any documentation / threads regarding the implementation of these tests in python?

Comment: Diehard is not one test, it's a whole suite of them.

Comment: yes I know, however, I can not find information on how to use this to test the Python generator